# Output of User-Defined Table Function Cannot to Converted to Stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink, flink-table-api

I have a datastream that I am converting to a Table so that I may use Flink SQL syntax on the table. My Flink SQL query includes a user-defined Table Function, meaning each input row results in multiple output row, using a generator as in the documentation. Here is my UDTF:

```
class CalculateValueDiff(TableFunction):
    def eval(message_time, ids, grouped_values, is_t1s):
        t1_players = [id for id, is_t1 in zip(ids, is_t1s) if is_t1]
        t2_players = [id for id, is_t1 in zip(ids, is_t1s) if not is_t1]

        for t1_player in t1_players:
            for t2_player in t2_players:
                value_diff = abs(grouped_values[ids.index(t1_player)] - grouped_values[ids.index(t2_player)])
                yield Row(value_diff, t1_player, t2_player)
```

Once I register this UDTF as `calculate_value_diff` (along with custom `collect_list_<T>` aggregators for different data types- those are working fine), I run this SQL query:

```
        res_table = t_env.sql_query("""
                                    SELECT 
                                        message_time,
                                        calculate_value_diff(
                                            collect_list_int(id),
                                            collect_list_float(value),
                                            collect_list_bool(is_t1)
                                        ) as value_diffs
                                    FROM InputTable
                                    GROUP BY message_time
                                    """)

        res_stream = t_env.to_changelog_stream(res_table)
```

The issue I'm having is the that output of the UDTF is technically a generator, not a row. So when I call `t_env.to_changelog_stream(res_table)`, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get_fields_by_names'`. It seems that stream converter expects a row (works fine if I replace the `yield` with `return`. But then I'm obviously only getting the first output value for the UDTF. Any advice?

Not sure how to proceed from here... What really needs to happy is the `pyflink.fn_execution.coder_impl_fast.RowCoderImpl.encode_to_stream` function needs to be adjusted to iterate through the generator is the value is a generator, but is there a way around this?